# Wanted to fetch api after getting true value from observable emitter in RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I am working on RxJava. I have created a random boolean stream of true and false values for observable class.

The observable class should be get repeated after a random duration of *x* seconds (between 10 and 90 seconds). After each true value, I need to call API and update the UI.

I have written the following code to generate random boolean values and pass them through observable. But how to repeat observable after every *x* seconds?

```
val r = Random
        val apiResultStream = Observable.create(object : Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean> {
            override fun call(subscriber: Subscriber<in Boolean>) {
                // emit true or false
                subscriber.onNext(r.nextBoolean())
            }
        }).repeat(10)

        apiResultStream
            .subscribe { result ->
                if (result === true) {

                    Log.v("ABC",""+result);
                    callAPI()

                } else {
                    //callFailureApi()
                    Log.v("ABC",""+result);
                }
            }
```

Comment: This code looks correct. What exactly do you want help in?

Comment: @PrashantPandey wanted to call observable after every 30 sec

Answer (score 1):

I guess `Observable.interval(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` is what you need:

```
Observable.interval(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) //also can specify scheduler
    .flatMap { apiResultStream }
    .subscribe { result ->
            if (result === true) {

                Log.v("ABC",""+result);
                callAPI()

            } else {
                //callFailureApi()
                Log.v("ABC",""+result);
            }
        }
```